# Classification of compact connected manifolds by fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, fundamental-groups

Every compact connected 2-manifold (I define this as a surface) is homeomorphic to a 2-sphere, a connected sum of tori or a connected sum of projective planes.
Since the fundamental groups of the surfaces in this list are not isomorphic then one can say that the fundamental group determines the topological type of every surface.
Is this true for manifolds of dimension greater than 2?
If not can you provide a counterexample as simple as possible?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space

Comment: @dcolazin You should post this as an answer.

Comment: If you add "aspherical" (i.e. with contractible universal covering space) then this becomes a famous conjecture (true and very difficult in dimension 3). The thing is that such manifolds are necessarily homotopy equivalent (if they have isomorphic fundamental groups).

Comment: [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720238/examples-of-same-fundamental-group-but-not-homeomorphic/1720323#1720323) is the same except without the "compactness" hypothesis, and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720238/examples-of-same-fundamental-group-but-not-homeomorphic/1720323#1720323) to that question explains compact counterexamples which are lens spaces.

Answer (score 1):

There are non-homeomorphic [lens spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space) with same fundamental group: $\pi_1(L(p,q)) = \mathbb{Z}_p$ ([here](https://wolfweb.unr.edu/homepage/jabuka/Classes/2008_fall/algtop/Notes/07%20-%20Lens%20spaces.pdf)), but $L(p,q_2) \cong L(p_2,q_2) \iff p = p_2$ and $(\pm q_1 q_2 \equiv_p 1$ or $\pm q_1 \equiv_p q_2 )$. I really don't remember where I studied the classification theorem, but [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0011119.pdf) you can find some references to several proofs.